# How display a list selection in a form onto a PDF

Tags: forms, list, acrobat, orbeon

I created a form with Orbeon Form Editor and I want to print a PDF with user's selection. Text, date, time, radio-buttons are correctly transmited to the PDF but I ca not get the selection in list objects. How to do that ?

I set both sides with the same values (in Form Editor and in Acrobat), correctly used the `section-x$field-y` name

The PDF field (either text or list) should show the user's selection. But it stays .

Comment: Laurent, what do you have on the Orbeon Forms side? Is it a dropdown? And what about on the PDF side? Could you share with us a few screenshots of the controls you have in your forms on both sides (Orbeon Forms and PDF)? ‑Alex

Comment: Hello, on my Form, I have a drop down list with 2 elements. I reproduced exactly the same structure in my PDF in a drop down list and named it as usual section$control.

Comment: Got it Laurent: I tested this, and populating dropdowns works for me, when making sure that the value specified in Form Builder corresponds to an option defined in the PDF (more details in my answer below). You'll let me know if this helps. ‑Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible issue is that PDFs, unlike Orbeon Forms, don't make a distinction between the "label" (what users see) and "value" (what is stored in the data). Orbeon Forms will populate the PDF with the value the user selected, so you need to make sure that value matches one of the options you provided in the PDF template.

Most likely, to keep things simple, you'll want to keep the label and value the same. For instance, for a dropdown allowing the selection of a number of children, in Form Builder you'd have:

[image]

Assuming your control is named `number` and is in a section named `children`, in the PDF, you'd have (here editing the dropdown with PDFescape):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your investigation. It seems that the reason it does not work is tied to the version of Orbeon I'm testing. It's an old 4.10 and I'm pretty sure it will work when my company will update to the new one (if they decide to do it). I used the same trick as you described but still does not work in the following scheme  : Orbeon dropdown list -> PDF dropdown list. But it works with Orbon dropdown list ->Orbeon text field-> PDF text field.

Comment: Hi Laurent, indeed, 4.10 is quite old. You could try with the latest version, just [downloading it](https://www.orbeon.com/download) and running it on the side, to see if it solves the problem. And if it does, you'll have narrowed down the problem, and have one more reason to upgrade :). ‑Alex